# How can I iterate over a file looking for keywords defined within a list

Tags: python

I have a defined list of keywords and a text file.  I would like to search the text file and count how many times each of the keywords within my list appear. Example:

```
kw = ['max speed', 'time', 'distance', 'travel', 'down', 'up']

with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    data_file = f.read()
    d = dict()
    for line in data_file:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.lower()
        words = line.split(" ")
        for word in words:
            if word in d:
                d[word] = d[word] + 1
            else:
                d[word] = 1
    for key in list(d.keys()):
        print(key, ":", d[key])
```

Now lets say we run the code, it should search the file.txt and loop through the list. If it finds a keyword in the list, then print that word and how many times it was found. If no word is found then it doesn't report.

Example output:

Keywords Found:

max speed: 3
travel: 7
distance: 3

Can't quite get this to work like I want. Any feedback would be great! Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Could you explain what is happening, instead of simply "Can't get this to work like I want"? We can help you better with more information.

Comment: can you add some example data of your text file ? at the moment you just loop through  all your text file and print out how often every word is in the text file. your question is how to implement the `kw` list. is that right ?

Comment: `for line in data_file` This isn't doing what you think.  `data_file` is the entire file contents as a string.  When you iterate over a string you get _individual characters_, not _lines_.  If you want lines, use `f.readlines()` instead of `f.read()`.

Comment: Thanks @JohnGordon. That makes sense, as that is exactly what I was getting, just individual characters with the number of occurrences. I'll give f.readlines() a go and see if I get more of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

There are several algorithms which you can use. There are special algorithms for finding a specific words in texts. The easiest one will be the **naive algorithm**, here is code that I wrote:

```py
def naive_string_matching(text, pattern):
    txt_len, pat_len = len(text), len(pattern)
    result = []
    for s in range(txt_len - pat_len + 1):
        if pattern == text[s:s+pat_len]:
            result.append(s)
    return result
```

This naive algorithm takes as an input a text and one word as a pattern to search for. The complexity of this algorithm is `O((n − m + 1)m)` where `m` is the length of pattern and `n` is the length of a text.

The next algorithm which you can use and has the better complexity than the **naive algorithm** is **Finite automation algorithm**. Here you can [read more about it](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/finite-automata-algorithm-for-pattern-searching/) if you are interested in it. Here is also my implementation of this algorithm:

```py
def transition_table(pattern):
    alphabet = set(pattern)
    ptt_len = len(pattern)
    result = []
    for q in range(ptt_len+1):
        result.append({})
        for l in alphabet:
            k = min(len(pattern), q+1)
            while True:
                if k == 0 or pattern[:k] == (pattern[:q] + l)[-k:]:
                    break
                k -= 1
            result[q][l] = k
    return result

def fa_string_matching(text, pattern):
    q = 0
    delta = transition_table(pattern)
    txt_len = len(text)
    result = []
    for s in range(txt_len):
        if text[s] in delta[q]:
            q = delta[q][text[s]]
            if q == len(delta) - 1:
                result.append(s+1-q)
        else:
            q = 0
    return result
```

The complexity of this algorithm is `O(n)` but pre-processing time (`transition_table` function) takes `O(m)` where again `n` is the length of a text and `m` the length of a pattern.

And the last one algorithm I can propose to you is the [KMP (Knuth–Morris–Pratt) algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) which is the fastest of all 3 of them. Again my implementation of it:

```py
def prefix_function(pattern):
    pat_len = len(pattern)
    pi = [0]
    k = 0
    for q in range(1, pat_len):
        while k > 0 and pattern[k] != pattern[q]:
            k = pi[k-1]
        if pattern[k] == pattern[q]:
            k += 1
        pi.append(k)
    return pi

def kmp_string_matching(text, pattern):
    txt_len, pat_len = len(text), len(pattern)
    pi = prefix_function(pattern)
    q = 0
    result = []
    for i in range(txt_len):
        while q > 0 and pattern[q] != text[i]:
            q = pi[q-1]
        if pattern[q] == text[i]:
            q += 1
        if q == pat_len:
            result.append(i - q + 1)
            q = pi[q-1]
    return result
```

As an input it takes full text and a pattern that you are looking for. The complexity of **KMP algorithm** is similar to the Finite automation algorithm and it is `O(n)` but the pre-processing time is faster (`prefix_function`).

If you are interested in such topics like pattern matching or finding the occurrences of a pattern in a text, I highly recommend you to become acquainted with all of them.

To open a file you can simply run:

```py
with open(file_name) as file:
    text = file.read()
    result = naive_string_matching(text, pattern)
```

where `file_name` is the name of your file, **pattern** is the phrase that you want to search for in the **text**. To search for patterns in an array you can try:

```py
example_patterns = ['max speed', 'time', 'distance', 'travel', 'down', 'up']
with open(file_name) as file:
    text = file.read()
    for pattern in example_patterns:
        result = kmp_string_matching(text, pattern)
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I'll definitely take a look at everything you provided.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

keywords = ['max speed', 'time', 'distance', 'travel', 'down', 'up']
keywords = [x.replace(' ', r'\s') for x in keywords]  # replaces spaces with whitespace indicator

with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()

keywords_found = {}
for key in keywords:
    found = re.findall(key, data, re.I) # re.I means it'll ignore case. 
    if found:
        keywords_found[key] = len(found)

print(keywords_found)
```